# Why plugin notice is showing inside the tab in WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a WordPress Plugin and it has 4 tabs.

Now, I have another plugin that is showing admin notice inside / between my plugin tab. See the picture:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

For this tab, I am using this action hook

```
add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_menu'));
```

Comment: Did you  check the name of the tab? could be that. try and change it.

Comment: don't understand? Can you clear it more?

Comment: This notice shows only in this tab?

Comment: Not in this tab. The main problem is why it's showing the admin notice inside the div of my plugin? It should be show top of my all plugin div, right?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a do_action() in your plugin near those tabs, and the other plugin has an add_action() function that targets any do_action() that has the same name.

If this is the case, rename your actions to something unique.